# Display Values of Chosen Check Boxes and Radio Buttons and Their Total on Alert Message

Tags: javascript, html

I pretty much figured out my whole system with the help of the people here. Now the only thing troubling me now is how to display the name and values of the chosen checkboxes and radio buttons and their total which is located at the textbox below the html. I have the validations of the checkboxes and radio buttons right, but for some reason the whole system won't work when I put them on the finalVal() function. I don't know what to do to fix this.

Here's my HTML :

```
<h2>We'd Like to Know More About You!</h2>
<form name="info">
Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "name" placeholder="Enter a valid name">*</br></br>
Address: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "address" placeholder="Enter a valid address"></br></br>
Email Address: &nbsp <input type="email" id = "inf" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">*</br></br>
Phone Number: &nbsp <input type = "tel" id = "inf" name ="PN"  placeholder="Enter a valid phone number">*</br></br>
<hr/> 
</form>

<h2>What Kind of Burger Would You Like to Order?</h2>
<form name ="burgz">

Add-ons <br/>
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="45" onchange="calculate(this);">Bacon - 45
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="40" onchange="calculate(this);">Sausage - 40
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="30" onchange="calculate(this);">Ham - 30
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="10" onchange="calculate(this);">Tomatoes - 10
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="3" onchange="calculate(this);">Peppers - 3
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="5" onchange="calculate(this);">Olives - 5
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="15" onchange="calculate(this);">Extra Cheese - 15
<br/>


Size<br/>
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="size"  value="10" onchange="calculate(this);">Small - 10
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="size" value="20" onchange="calculate(this);">Medium - 20
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="size" value="30" onchange="calculate(this);">Large - 30
<input type="hidden" name="size">
<br/>


Shape<br/>
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="shape" value="15" onchange="calculate(this);">Round - 15
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="shape" value="10" onchange="calculate(this);">Square - 10
<input type="hidden" name="shape">
<br/>

<p>Total Price: <input type="text" name="total_price" value="0" readonly="readonly"></p>
<input type = "button" onClick = "displayInfo()" value ="Submit Info">
</form>
</body>
```

Here's my Javascript :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

///////////validations
function ValEntry(){
    var valid = true;

    if ( document.info.name.value== ""||document.info.address.value== ""||document.info.email.value== ""||document.info.PN.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please fill up the remaining text boxes" );
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

function checkemail(){
    var testresults1
    var str=document.info.email.value
    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i

    if (filter.test(str))
    testresults1=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid email address!")
    testresults1=false
    }
return (testresults1)
}

function checkphone(){
    var testresults2
    var int = document.info.PN.value
    var filter2= /[1-9]/g;

    if (filter2.test(int))
    testresults2=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid phone number!")
    testresults2=false
}
return (testresults2)
}

function validate(){
    if (document.info.email.value)
    return checkemail()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

function validate2(){
    if (document.info.PN.value)
    return checkphone()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

function validateCheck()
{
    if (document.burgz.AO[0].checked == false &&
        document.burgz.AO[1].checked == false &&
        document.burgz.AO[2].checked == false &&
        document.burgz.AO[3].checked == false &&
        document.burgz.AO[4].checked == false &&
        document.burgz.AO[5].checked == false &&
        document.burgz.AO[6].checked == false)
        {
            alert("Please pick any add-ons of your choice.");

        }
        return false;
        return true;

}


function validateRadio()
{
    if (document.burgz.size[0].checked) return true;
    if (document.burgz.size[1].checked) return true;
    if (document.burgz.size[2].checked) return true;
    if (document.burgz.size.value == false);
    {
        alert("Please choose a size.");

    }
        return;
}
function validateRadio2()
{
    if (document.burgz.shape[0].checked) return true;
    if (document.burgz.shape[1].checked) return true;
    if (document.burgz.shape.value == false);
    {
        alert("Please choose a shape.");

    }
        return;
}



function FinalVal(){
    return ValEntry() && validate() && validate2();

}


///////////auto-total 

var lastSizeVal = 0;
var lastShapeVal = 0;

function calculate(input) {
    var total = parseInt(burgz.total_price.value);
    var value = parseInt(input.value);

    if (input.type === 'radio') {
        if (input.name === 'size') {
            total -= lastSizeVal;
            lastSizeVal = value;
        }
        else {
            total -= lastShapeVal;
            lastShapeVal = value;
        }
    }

    if (input.checked)
        burgz.total_price.value = total + value
    else
        burgz.total_price.value = total - value;
}


////////////Display information


function displayInfo(){
if (FinalVal()) 

    {
        var fields=["name", "address", "email", "PN"];
        var fieldNames=["Name", "Address", "Email Address", "Phone Number"];
        var msg = "";

        for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
            msg += fieldNames[i] + ": " + document.info[ fields[i] ].value + "\n";


        alert(msg);
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `FinalVal` function inside if condition:

```
function displayInfo(){
    if (FinalVal()) {
        var fields=["name", "address", "email", "PN"];
        var fieldNames=["Name", "Address", "Email Address", "Phone Number"];
        var msg = "";
        for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
            msg += fieldNames[i] + ": " + document.info[ fields[i] ].value + "\n";
        alert(msg);
    }
    return true;
}
```

It means that if `FinalVal` function returns any falsy value then condition will not be executed and alert will not be shown.
Now if you add all your validations to your function it will look this way:

```
function FinalVal(){
    return ValEntry() && validate() && validate2() && validateRadio() && validateRadio2() && validateCheck();
}
```

But your `validateCheck` or `validateRadio` functions always return undefined (remember that simple `return` without value returns undefined which is falsy value).
To fix this problem, change your validation functions so that it explicitly returns true or false values like the following:

```js
///////////validations
function ValEntry(){
    var valid = true;

    if ( document.info.name.value== ""||document.info.address.value== ""||document.info.email.value== ""||document.info.PN.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please fill up the remaining text boxes" );
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

function checkemail(){
    var testresults1
    var str=document.info.email.value
    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i

    if (filter.test(str))
    testresults1=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid email address!")
    testresults1=false
    }
return (testresults1)
}

function checkphone(){
    var testresults2
    var int = document.info.PN.value
    var filter2= /[1-9]/g;

    if (filter2.test(int))
    testresults2=true
    else{
    alert("Please input a valid phone number!")
    testresults2=false
}
return (testresults2)
}

function validate(){
    if (document.info.email.value)
    return checkemail()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

function validate2(){
    if (document.info.PN.value)
    return checkphone()
    else{
    return true
    }       
}

    function validateCheck()
    {
        if (document.burgz.AO[0].checked == false &&
            document.burgz.AO[1].checked == false &&
            document.burgz.AO[2].checked == false &&
            document.burgz.AO[3].checked == false &&
            document.burgz.AO[4].checked == false &&
            document.burgz.AO[5].checked == false &&
            document.burgz.AO[6].checked == false)
            {
                alert("Please pick any add-ons of your choice.");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

    }


    function validateRadio()
    {
        if (document.burgz.size[0].checked) return true;
        if (document.burgz.size[1].checked) return true;
        if (document.burgz.size[2].checked) return true;
        if (document.burgz.size.value == false)
        {
            alert("Please choose a size.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateRadio2()
    {
        if (document.burgz.shape[0].checked) return true;
        if (document.burgz.shape[1].checked) return true;
        if (document.burgz.shape.value == false)
        {
            alert("Please choose a shape.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }



function FinalVal(){
    return ValEntry() && validate() && validate2() && validateRadio() && validateRadio2() && validateCheck();

}


///////////auto-total 

var lastSizeVal = 0;
var lastShapeVal = 0;

function calculate(input) {
    var total = parseInt(burgz.total_price.value);
    var value = parseInt(input.value);

    if (input.type === 'radio') {
        if (input.name === 'size') {
            total -= lastSizeVal;
            lastSizeVal = value;
        }
        else {
            total -= lastShapeVal;
            lastShapeVal = value;
        }
    }

    if (input.checked)
        burgz.total_price.value = total + value
    else
        burgz.total_price.value = total - value;
}


////////////Display information


function displayInfo(){
if (FinalVal()) 

    {
        var fields=["name", "address", "email", "PN"];
        var fieldNames=["Name", "Address", "Email Address", "Phone Number"];
        var msg = "";

        for(i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
            msg += fieldNames[i] + ": " + document.info[ fields[i] ].value + "\n";


        alert(msg);
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
    <h2>We'd Like to Know More About You!</h2>
    <form name="info">
        Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "name" placeholder="Enter a valid name">*</br></br>
        Address: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type = "text" id = "inf" name = "address" placeholder="Enter a valid address"></br></br>
        Email Address: &nbsp <input type="email" id = "inf" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address">*</br></br>
        Phone Number: &nbsp <input type = "tel" id = "inf" name ="PN"  placeholder="Enter a valid phone number">*</br></br>
        <hr/> 
    </form>

    <h2>What Kind of Burger Would You Like to Order?</h2>
    <form name ="burgz">

        Add-ons <br/>
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="45" onchange="calculate(this);">Bacon - 45
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="40" onchange="calculate(this);">Sausage - 40
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="30" onchange="calculate(this);">Ham - 30
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="10" onchange="calculate(this);">Tomatoes - 10
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="3" onchange="calculate(this);">Peppers - 3
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="5" onchange="calculate(this);">Olives - 5
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="AO"  value="15" onchange="calculate(this);">Extra Cheese - 15
        <br/>


        Size<br/>
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="size"  value="10" onchange="calculate(this);">Small - 10
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="size" value="20" onchange="calculate(this);">Medium - 20
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="size" value="30" onchange="calculate(this);">Large - 30
        <input type="hidden" name="size">
        <br/>


        Shape<br/>
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="shape" value="15" onchange="calculate(this);">Round - 15
        &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="shape" value="10" onchange="calculate(this);">Square - 10
        <input type="hidden" name="shape">
        <br/>

        <p>Total Price: <input type="text" name="total_price" value="0" readonly="readonly"></p>
        <input type = "button" onClick = "displayInfo()" value ="Submit Info">
    </form>
```

Comment: I tried this before actually... I tried it again when you posted it, but the whole system still doesn't work for some unknown reason.